# SharePoint Online doesn't honor single page app (SPA) settings for user with read permissions to the page

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are running into issue where when we have broken the permission on modern site pages with read permission SharePoint doesn't honor Single Page App (SPA) settings and render page as regular page when user with read permissions to pages logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the page isn't published.